# My Java matrix multiply code single thread faster than multithreading, any mistakes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm implementing the matrix multiply function using Java's multithreading. Below is my code:
So I first tried the normal single threaded approach, then tried the ExecutorService approach, I don't know why the first approach is actually faster than the multithreading approach, based on the start time and the end time, is there any mistake in my code?

```
public class MatrixTest {
    static int len = 1000;
    static int[][] m1 = new int[len][len];
    static int[][] m2 = new int[len][len];
    static int[][] res = new int[len][len];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        initMatrix(m1);
        initMatrix(m2);
        //ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //res = new MatrixMulty().multi(m1, m2);

        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
                MatrixMulty mm = new MatrixMulty(m1[i], getCol(m2, j), res, i, j);
                //executorService.submit(mm);
                mm.multi();
            }
        }
        //executorService.shutdown();
        //executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("whole time is :" + (endTime - startTime) / 10000);
    }

    private static int[] getCol(int[][] m2, int j) {
        int[] re = new int[m2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m2.length; i++) {
            re[i] = m2[i][j];
        }
        return re;
    }

    private static void initMatrix(int[][] mtx) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mtx.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mtx[0].length; j++) {
                mtx[i][j] = i+j;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MatrixMulty implements Runnable {

    int[] m1;
    int[] m2;
    int[][] res;
    int i;
    int j;
    public MatrixMulty(int[] m1, int[] m2, int[][] res, int i, int j){
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.res = res;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int index=0;
        int r = 0;
        while(index<m1.length){
            r += m1[index]*m2[index];
            index++;
        }
        res[i][j] = r;
    }

    public void multi() {
        int index=0;
        int r = 0;
        while(index<m1.length){
            r += m1[index]*m2[index];
            index++;
        }
        res[i][j] = r;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1**
Based on suggestion, I have modified related code and move the executorService from the inner loop to the outer loop, new code sinppets shows below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        initMatrix(m1);
        initMatrix(m2);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(45);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //res = new MatrixMulty().multi(m1, m2);

        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
            MatrixMulty2 mm = new MatrixMulty2(m1[i], m2, res, i);
            //for (int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
                //MatrixMulty mm = new MatrixMulty(m1[i], getCol(m2, j), res, i, j);
                //executorService.submit(mm);
                //mm.multi();
            //}
            executorService.submit(mm);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("whole time is :" + (endTime - startTime) / 10000);
    }
```

and the new class MatrixMulty2:

```
public class MatrixMulty2 implements Runnable {

    int[] m1;
    int[][] m2;
    int[][] res;
    int i;

    public MatrixMulty2(int[] m1, int[][] m2, int[][] res, int i){
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.res=res;
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int j=0;j<m2[0].length;j++){
            int[] co = getCol(m2,j);
            int index=0;
            int r = 0;
            while(index<m1.length){
                r += m1[index]*co[index];
                index++;
            }
            res[i][j] = r;
        }
    }

    private static int[] getCol(int[][] m2, int j) {
        int[] re = new int[m2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m2.length; i++) {
            re[i] = m2[i][j];
        }
        return re;
    }
}
```

After testing, I find that it is faster than the single thread approach by around 25%. Is there any more to optimize it? or from pool size aspect, here I have a fixed thread pool with size=50, I find that it is not true that the larger thread pool I have, the faster it runs. Here size=50 is an ad-hoc value, is it possible to systematically tune it?

Comment: Try submitting in the *outer* loop. Present measurement results of all alternatives measured.

Comment: Thanks, I've made changes. What do you mean by "Present measurement results of all alternatives measured"@greybeard

Comment: I'm not 100% thinking straight right now, but I believe your number of operations being run is a little bit low, and your number of threads a little bit high. You should have around a million integer operations, that's *nothing*. Threads are expensive to start and slow down the moment you run out of (physical?) cores. So for performance tests you might also want to test with a higher operations count and also with a lower thread count.